# C# progress bar not synced with download (WebClient class)

Tags: c#, ftp, webclient

I am coding a system which has a small FTP module included inside, it's not the main feature at all, but needed...

I must link the progressbar with the WebClient class event DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler and AsyncCompletedEventHandler, the progressbar increment is ok, and the ASyncCompletedEventHandler launch a MessageBox (as intended), the problem is that the progress bar see to load too slow...

problem :

My MessageBox pop at 100% (launched by the event handler), BUT when the MessageBox pop my progress bar is only at +-80% (but the .VALUE is really 100), the first though I had was that they have added a "smooth" effect in Windows Vista which slow down the progressbar relatively to it's true value.

If any of you have experienced the same problem thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you who want to know, Vista actually add a "smoothing" to the loadingbar change, it look like the "Tweening effect" of Flash.

I tried on Windows XP and the bar reach 100% exactly when the value reach 100. On Vista it look like they have decided that the "loading" would be splitted over a delay X.

Answer (score 0):

Before you display your message box, call **[Application.DoEvents()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx)** to force all the pending Windows queued messages to be processed.  Your progress bar is probably not getting a chance to paint itself one last time before the message box displays.

Comment: The progress bar should process messages while the dialog is visible too.

Comment: I can't post image because I don't have enought reputation here, but the bar is not 1-2tick away, it's 20% away (20% being about 2second delay). 

I did a test with Application.DoEvents() and it doesn't look like it changed anything, it's still arround 80-85% (visually), and the value is 100.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply set the progress bar value to 100% on the same DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler event handler that displays the message box?

Comment: hehe, I tried that too, as previously said I think it might be caused because they made in go "smooth" i.e if it goes from 0 to 100 it will do it slowly like 100% increase splitted over 1 second instead of "instant 100%".

It might has something to do with Windows Vista, I'll try on a XP pc soon to see if the same "smoothing" effect happen.